# First cohomology and permutation action

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain and let $G$ be a finite group acting on $R[x_1, .., x_n]$ by permuting the $x_i$. Is $H^1(G,R[x_1, .., x_n]) =0$? If not, are there any conditions on $R$ which insure that?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a very fruitful approach, but this was my first thought: if instead of $R[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ you simply had $S_n$ acting on the regular representation with coefficients in $R$ ($M = \bigoplus_{1\leq i\leq n} Rx_i$), you could use Shapiro's lemma to tell you that $H^1(S_n, M)\cong H^1(S_{n-1}, R)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(S_{n-1},R)$. Then you could use an exact sequence $0\to M\to R[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to Q\to 0$, but that would still leave you with trying to understand $H^1(S_n,Q)$...

Comment: Maybe there's some other simpler exact sequence of $S_n$-modules involving $R[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ for which the LES in cohomology would give you something useful.

Comment: Perhaps something with induction, looking at $0\to R[x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}]\to R[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to Q\to 0$, if you can get a handle on $Q$?